# Update ID record in one table with values from another table

Tags: sql-server

We have two tables (MS SQL)

1- Asset table, Contains AssetCode, CustodianID and DepartmentID
    This department ID where is the asset located

2- Custodian table, Containes CustodianID and DepartmentID
    This department ID where is that custodian belongs to

**Situation:** 
Sometimes a user transfer from department 1 to department 2
Accordingly, the data entry person moves all his assets from department 1 to department 2 in the asset master screen and ignore to change the custodian department in the custodian master screen, now we can find a user where his department in the custodian master still department 1 while his assets already moved to department 2

**Required :**
Update Custodian table DepartmentID to match with Assets table DepartmentID for the same CustodianID

Comment: It will be good if you post sample data

Comment: Why do you have departmentId in your asset table, if the department is always that of the custodian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your written logic would seem to imply an update join based on the common custodian.

```
UPDATE c
SET DepartmentID = a.DepartmentID
FROM Custodian c
INNER JOIN Assets a
    ON c.CustodianID = a.CustodianID;
```

Note that it is strange that both tables have a `CustodianID` and a `DepartmentID`.  Your data probably is not normalized, but maybe this update is a step you are taking in the right direction.

Comment: what happened is sometimes the user moves to another department, but his assets remain in the old department, that is why,
however, i was trying the sent update query, but again didnt work, i believe the alias is not supported with the update statement, Im using sql 2014

Comment: The alias IS supported in an update join.  You must have copied my answer wrongly.

Comment: thank you man, it worked, before i copied your query without updating the table names to match mine
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can always add a second updated where the first one is located.

`UPDATE Custodian INNER JOIN   Assets ON Custodian.DepartmentID = Assets.DepartmentID SET Custodian.DepartmentID = Assets.DepartmentID`

This update will make sure that the custodians DepartmentID is the same as the Assets Department ID

edit:
This is for MySQL sorry

Comment: This is MySQL syntax.

Comment: I updated the query to match my tables names, to be like 
UPDATE CustodianTable INNER JOIN AssetTable ON CustodianTable.DepartmentID = AssetTable.DepartmentID SET CustodianTable.DepartmentID = AssetTable.DepartmentID

im getting the error message:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.